# Python plotly is working in command line but not in python file - import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, plotly, python-module

plolty 4.5.4 has been installed via conda install -c plotly plotly
python version: 3.7.6

in anaconda CLI, the following lines from plotly quickstart guide display a beautiful plotly graph:
[image]

However the same content in a .py file:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]))
fig.write_html('first_figure.html', auto_open=True)
```

And then a launch of this file:

```
python plotly.py
```

results in an import error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "plotly.py", line 1, in module
>       from plotly import graph_objs as go
>     File "plotly.py", line 1, in 
>       from plotly import graph_objs as go
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'graph_objs' from 'plotly'

Can anyone helps ?

Comment: Don't name your file `plotly.py`, that shadows the name of the `plotly` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the well known [name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap).

Just name the file differently from any standard library, third party package, or module that the application relies on.

Comment: thanks... The worst is that this is not the first time I fall in this trap...